# Two long sharp teeth

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Two long sharp teeth
>
> Two holes beneath
>
> My bite is neat
>
> I do not eat

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well this is far fetched, but let's try:
It is

> scissors

Two long sharp teeth

> Scissor has two blades

Two holes beneath

> you can make two holes with their blades, or as @Shahriar Mahmud Sajid mentioned in comments, it can refer to the two holes used to hold the scissors.

My bite is neat

> When they cut something, they cut neat

I do not eat

> they don't eat :)

Comment: i think second clue refers to- ROT13(gur gjb ubyrf hfrq gb ubyq gur fpvffbef)

Comment: Bingo, Yahtzee, Checkmate, We have a winner, and so on. +1

Answer (score 9):

You are

> a stapler.

Two long sharp teeth

> the sharp ends of the staple pointing out

Two holes beneath

> the two holes at the bottom force the staple to bend

My bite is neat

> bites through paper

I do not eat

> yep

Comment: Close! Very close. But not quite. My teeth are my own and they are longer and sharper.

Answer (score 7):

Let's give this a try:

> a paper punch
>  
>  
>  Leaves two neat holes in paper with long metal rods and doesn't require to eat.

Comment: Also very close.  But my teeth are longer and sharper still :)